# JSON not supported assertion type

Tags: node.js, json, yarnpkg

```
node:internal/errors:464
9:07:48 PM:     ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
9:07:48 PM:     ^
9:07:48 PM: TypeError [ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING]: Module "file:///opt/build/repo/.contentlayer/generated/Blog/blog__BLANK.mdx.json" needs an import assertion of type
```

But I have
--experimental-json-modules as a build option

I am really stumped when I remove the offending json files it works, strangely i have a newsletter which works very similarly ending with .json and it works.

Comment: hi, how did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need `assert` after the import:

```js
// "(node:3933) ExperimentalWarning: Import assertions are not a stable feature of the JavaScript language.
// Avoid relying on their current behavior and syntax as those might change in a future version of Node.js."
// The proposed official syntax is `with` instead of `assert`. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes

import json_object from "./blog__BLANK.mdx.json" assert { type: "json" };
console.log("typeof json_object =", typeof json_object); // typeof json_object = object
```